# Do db:reset for specific seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

Can I do `db:reset` in specific seed file, not whole database? Because I don't need reset full database with all data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you looking for is [seed_fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu). This gem will allow you to create seed files with assigned ids so you can reseed them as many times as you needed without loosing of other data in database.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way of doing this.

Comment out what all you don't require to be loaded from the `seed.rb` file when doing a `db:reset`.

Then run `db:reset`. It will do what you need.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: please let me know if you find any other ways of doing it.